# La conversión del tipo de datos produjo un valor fuera de intervalo para fecha en SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy ejecutando una instruccion en sql pero me genera el error

> La conversión del tipo de datos nvarchar en datetime produjo un valor fuera de intervalo.

castie la fecha pero me sigue dando el mismo error, los datos con que realizo mi instruccion son

```html
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @IdPeriod  INT = 29

SET @EndDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, FORMAT(@EndDate, CONCAT('yyyy-MM-', IIF(@IdPeriod < 10, CONCAT('0', @IdPeriod), (@IdPeriod )), 'T00:00:00.000')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No esta nada claro cual es tú objetivo, pero lo que estás haciendo siempre va a darte ese error, porque le estás dando una fecha fuera de rango.

Partiendo en cachos lo que haces.

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @IdPeriod INT = 29;
select Iif(
                            @IdPeriod < 10, 
                            CONCAT(
                                '0', 
                                @IdPeriod),
                            @IdPeriod)
```

[image: Result]

El año 2022 no tiene un día 29 de Febrero. Por eso te da ese error.

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @IdPeriod INT = 29;
select              FORMAT(
                    @EndDate, 
                    CONCAT(
                        'yyyy-MM-', 
                        Iif(
                            @IdPeriod < 10, 
                            CONCAT(
                                '0', 
                                @IdPeriod),
                            @IdPeriod), 
                        'T00:00:00.000')
                        )
```

[image: Result2]

Esto es lo que tienes justo antes de utilizar `dateAdd`

La función dateadd en su documentación dice.

> **Argumento date DATEADD**
> no aceptará un argumento date incrementado a un
> valor fuera del intervalo de su tipo de datos. En las instrucciones
> siguientes, el valor number que se agrega al valor date supera el
> intervalo del tipo de datos date. DATEADD devuelve el mensaje de error
> siguiente: "Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Adding a value to a
> 'datetime' column caused overflow".

[DateAdd](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Suponiendo que el objetivo sea a una fecha, sumarle unos días, para obtener un resultado con el formato esperado, no tienes que cambiar el tipo de dato. Utiliza directamente datetime, añade la fecha que corresponda y dale el formato de salida que quieras.

```
Set dateFormat ymd
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000';
Select 
    FORMAT(DATEADD(day,5,@endDate),'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000')
union all Select
    FORMAT(DATEADD(day,27,@endDate),'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000')
union all Select
    FORMAT(DATEADD(day,28,@endDate),'yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00.000');
```

[image: Result]

La salida, para un día de un dígito, para el último día del mes y para el siguiente, que ya se va a marzo.

Si necesitas que esté dentro del rango del mes, también dispones desde `Sql Server 2012` o superior, de la función [eoMonth](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: y como podria meter la validacion dentro de mi instruccion para evitar ese error?

Comment: He editado la pregunta, para intentar apoyarte, pero sigue sin estar claro el objetivo. Si necesitas más ayuda, tendrás que editar la pregunta y exponer lo que necesitas realmente.